# How to refresh squid cache after a time interval

Tags: squid

How can I change the cache time limit in Squid so that after a time interval
the cache is cleared or refreshed ?.

Supratik

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the setting inside `squid` itself, but you could `cron` squid to restart and flush its cache every X-many hours.